# Given $(AX ^ T + B) ^ T = X + B$,$A$ is a symmetric matrix and $B$ is an antisymmetric matrix

Tags: matrices

I don't have the answers to this but can someone correct I can't see the mistake.

[image: Exercise]

Comment: The transpose of a matrix $A$ is denoted by $A^t$ or $A^T$, not $A^+$. The notation $A^+$ usually means something else, such as Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse.

Comment: Check the 5th line, we have $A$ is symmetric so $A^T = A$ and $B$ is antisymmetric so $B^T = -B$. Also, check the last line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
& (AX^T + B)^T & = X + B \\
\implies & XA^T + B^T & = X + B \\
\implies & XA^T - X & = -B^T + B
\end{split}
\end{equation}

We have $A$ is symmetric and $B$ is antisymmetric, so:

$$ A^T = A, \qquad \text{and} \qquad B^T = -B$$

Then

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
& \qquad XA^T - X & = -B^T + B \\
& \implies XA - X & = B + B \\
& \implies X(A - I) & = 2B \\
& \implies X &= 2B(A - I)^{-1}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 3):

The issue is on the last line. You need to multiply with $(A-I)^{-1}$ on the right. So you will get answer A

Answer (score 0):

According to the law of transpose, from $(AX^T+B)^T=X+B)$ we get $XA^T+B^T=X+B$.
Now $B^T=-B$ and $A^T=A$ so this reduces to $AX-B=X+B$ and $(A-I)X=2B$.

**IF!!!!!!!!** $A-I$ is regular, then $X=2(A-I)^{-1}B$ but it might not be the case (see $A=I$ for example).